# PHP PDO send e-mail code only sends if text-only - need to send HTML

Tags: php, email, pdo

I'm making this code that (1) moves records from one table to another (in the same database), (2) sends the contents of table 1 to a pre-determined e-mail, and (3) delete the contents of table 1 - simulating an "add to cart" feature.

My problem is that the code below will only be successful in sending the e-mail if $headers is not sent on mail(). However, I need to send the table contents as HTML or at least allow for

for the different records. If by any chance the e-mail isn't sent, then the delete part of the code isn't executed either. what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**Modified code (that works if I DON'T send `$headers`)**

```
<?php
    include '../config/database.php';
    date_default_timezone_set('CET');
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $query = "INSERT INTO claims_archive (t20pctID, total_amount, user_id, sent) SELECT t20pctID, total_amount, user_id, @date FROM cart WHERE t20pctID LIKE '%sony%'";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $query = "SELECT t.t20pctID, t.main_artist, t.track_title, t.original_album, c.total_amount FROM cart c LEFT JOIN tblclaims t ON t.t20pctID = c.t20pctID WHERE t.t20pctID LIKE '%sony%' ORDER BY t.main_artist";  
        $stmt=$con->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $to = "testmail2@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Test";
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: Test <testmail1@mail.com>" . "\r\n";
        $body = "Sent on: ". $date . "-\r\n";
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            extract($row);
            $body .= "Track title: ".$row ["track_title"]. "-";
        }
        $success = mail($headers, $to, $subject, $body);
        if ($success) {
            $query_delete = "DELETE FROM cart WHERE t20pctID LIKE '%sony%'";
            $stmt = $con->prepare($query_delete);
            $stmt->execute(); 
            header('Location: cart.php?action=sent');
        } else {
            header('Location: cart.php?action=sent_failed');
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: cart.php?action=sent_failed');
    }

    include 'layout_foot.php';
?>
```

**Original code**

```
<?php
    include '../config/database.php';
    date_default_timezone_set('CET');
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $query = "INSERT INTO claims_archive (t20pctID, total_amount, user_id, sent) SELECT t20pctID, total_amount, user_id, @date FROM cart WHERE t20pctID LIKE '%sony%'";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        //header('Location: cart.php?action=sent'); //please disregard this line as I forgot to remove it when I wrote this post.
        $query = "SELECT t.t20pctID, t.main_artist, t.track_title, t.original_album, c.total_amount FROM cart c LEFT JOIN tblclaims t ON t.t20pctID = c.t20pctID WHERE t.t20pctID LIKE '%sony%' ORDER BY t.main_artist";  
        $stmt=$con->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $to = "testmail2@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Test";
        $headers = "Test <testmail1@mail.com>". "\r\n". "MIME-Version: 1.0" ."\r\n". "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" ."\r\n";
        $body = "Sent on: ". $date . "-";
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            extract($row);
            $body .= "Track title: ".$row ["track_title"]. "-";
        }
        $success = mail($to, $subject, $body);
        if ($success) {
            header('Location: cart.php?action=sent');
        } else {
            header('Location: cart.php?action=sent_failed');
        }

        $query_delete = "DELETE FROM cart WHERE t20pctID LIKE '%sony%'";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($query_delete);
        $stmt->execute(); 
    } else {
        header('Location: cart.php?action=sent_failed');
    }

    include 'layout_foot.php';
?>
```

Comment: Your redirecting before sending email - your header use makes no sense

Comment: Hi Dagon. Thanks for pointing that out. I forgot to remove the first redirect. The issue still occurs tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
$success = mail($headers, $to, $subject, $body);
```

has not the right parameter order ...

See http://php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php The correct signature is this:

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message 
         [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

so

```
$success = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: That solved it! I can't believe the answer was right there all along! Thank you so much everyone!!!! @Shrikant D I cannot give you any up votes :/

Comment: aaaaaaah. I thought upvotes were different from accepting as a right answer. Shrikant found minor issues that also helped :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Your delete code will not be executed in any case since your are redirecting before this code run.

1. Remove `header('Location: cart.php?action=sent');` written just
   below to `if ($stmt->execute()) {`.
2. Place your delete code in `if($success)` condition before header.
3. Update $headers variable with below code and include it into your mail function:

   ```
   $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'From: Test <testmail1@mail.com>' . "\r\n";
   ```

Comment: Hi Shrikant D. I did the modifications you suggested and the issue is still there. I updated the OP... this is giving me a headache... Thanks for trying anyway!

Comment: @Hola: Code you mentioned above is the updated one. Delete product query should run before you sent your header information. So, Your delete SQL query should be placed within the `if($success)` condition or before it.

Comment: @Hola: `mail($headers, $to, $subject, $body)` should be `mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)`